# Delete Statement For Logic Defined in the Below Section

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Please help me write a Delete query for the below scenario. See below table. I need to delete those `itemID`s from the table if at least one `Flag` for that item is `true`. In the below case the item `A53-30374` should be deleted because at least one of the `Flags` is `true`.

```
itemid    Flag
------------------
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000001    0    
V0000002    1    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0     
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0    
V0000002    0
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make it self-contained.  A question on Stack Overflow should not require an external link to be understood -- so, include the data in the question itself.  (Also, tag the question correctly with the database you are using.)

Comment: Gordon, i cannot post the image because i am new to stack overflow so i had to post the link. Please see the image of the table in the link and i am using sql server database.

Comment: You should include the data as a text table in the question.  For formatting. place four spaces before each row.

Comment: The question is a little vague around **if only one flag is true**

Comment: Drew, the query should delete all the rows with itemid=A53-30374 because at least one flag is true.

Comment: Ok so if one or more they all get deleted for that itemid. How about scg's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from your_table 
where itemid in 
(select itemid from your_table 
where RELEASETOAX_YN = 1);
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you Drew

Comment: Hi @visionet please mark as answer if this helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL way to do this is:

```
delete from t
     where 1 = (select count(*)
                from t t2
                where t.itemId = t2.itemId and t2.flag = 1
               );
```

Although standard syntax, the version for MySQL is slightly different.

Note:  The above is specifically about finding exactly *1* row with the flag = 1.  If you just want to delete any id that has at least one flag = 1, then the more efficient way is:

```
delete from t
     where exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t.itemId = t2.itemId and t2.flag = 1
                  );
```

Comment: Gordon, it is deleting all the rows whereas it should only delete the entire ItemID where at least one flag is true.

Comment: @visionet . . . Both of these should delete all item ids if (exactly or at least) one of the item ids has a flag of 1.  If none of the flags are set to 1, then the `itemId` should not be deleted -- that is how the correlation clause works.